# Powershell Partial Match Strings Password Complexity

Tags: string, powershell, string-matching

I have two strings coming from a csv file:

```
$Password = "dkjhfd22dnrhfg"
$Username = "NewUser22d"
```

I'm trying to check for this: 
Not contain the user's account name or parts of the user's full name that exceed two consecutive characters.

If 3 or more characters are matched I would like to add it here:

```
if(($password -cmatch '[a-z]') -and ($password -cmatch '[A-Z]') -and ($password -match '\d') -and (($password).length -ge 18))
```

Questions:

1. How do I match?
2. How do I add to existing if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would be easier to run a function

Since you dont really need to look for (more then) the minimum password / username match

```
Function Check-Password{
    param(
        [string]$Username,
        [string]$Password,
        [int]$MatchLength
    )
    for($i = 0; $i -ne ($Username.Length - ($MatchLength - 1)); $i++){
        $Username.Substring($i, $MatchLength) | Where-Object {$Password -like "*$_*"}
    }
}

Check-Password -Username "NewUser22d" -Password "dkjhfd22dnrhfg" -MatchLength 3
```

This will return

```
22d
```